# Query to get sum of an employees commission

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Query to get total commissions for an employee, and update their totalCommission column in the employee table.

This query is run every few days (batch).

The rules:
1. **an employee can only get a maximum of $100/day of commision**, if they get more than $100 it just gets set to $100.

Tables:

```
Employee 
  (employeeID INT PK, totalCommissions INT, username, ...)

Sale 
  (saleID INT PK, employeeID INT FK, saleTotal, commission, created DATETIME)
```

**Using SQL Server 2005.**

So this query will have to group by day I presume, and use a case statement to set the daily commision to $100 if the sum is > 100 for that day, and then set the total SUM for all days to the Employee.TotalCommission column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you are limiting the dates somewhere using value of "somedate-goes-here":

```
update employee set totalcommissions = totalc
from
(
-------------------------------------
-- sum capped commissions by employee
-------------------------------------
select employeeID, sum(sum_commissions) as totalc from
      (
      ---------------------------------------
      -- make sure sum is capped if necessary
      ---------------------------------------
              select employeeID
              , case when sum_of_c > 100 then 100 else sum_of_c as sum_commisions
              from 
              (
              -----------------------------------------------
              -- get sum of  commissions per day per employee
              -----------------------------------------------
              select employeeID, sum(commission) as sum_of_c from sale
              where created > "somedate-goes-here"
              group by employeeID, day(created)
              ) as x
      ) as c
  group by employeeID
) y 
inner join employee on employee.employeeID = y.employeeID
```

Comment: Is DAY(created) safe?  will it confuse jan.21 and feb.21 , etc. as all being the same day? (since it is ignoring the month/year?)

Comment: DAY(date) gives you the day portion of your date - for both Jan.21 and Feb.21, you'll get "21" as the value

Comment: marc_s so then the query won't work, since jan.21 and feb.21 are different days, I guess you have to break down the date forther to include month/year also.